# How to change to a specific folder using cmd without caring about the whole path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am at a specific folder lets say `users/personal/project/scripts`. Is there a way to go to the `project` folder without caring about what is before `/project`, that is without caring about the `users/personal/` in a python script?

I am looking for a way, other than

```
import os

os.chdir('..')
```

Comment: Could you explain what your usecase is and why `chdir('..')` does not solve your problem?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I am more deep inside the folder `project`. 

And the reason that I want it to be "whole path independent" is because I might have cloned a repo inside the `users/personal/` and a colleague of mine might have cloned it inside the `users/`

Comment: @quant If any of the answers correctly answer your question, please accept them as the correct answer, if not comment, on the answers, why they do not answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` of `os.path` module.

```
import os
import os.path

some_path = '/users/personal/project/scripts'
base_path, child = os.path.split(some_path)
os.chdir(base_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` module with the `os.cwd()` and `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, os.pardir))` in order to achieve this. GeeksforGeeks has a great article, which has multiple answers to your question:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-parent-of-current-directory-using-python/

**METHOD 1:**

> ```py
> import os 
> # get current directory
> path = os.getcwd()
> print("Current Directory", path)
> print()    
> # parent directory
> parent = os.path.dirname(path)
> print("Parent directory", parent)
> ```

**METHOD 2:**

> ```py
> import os    
> # get current directory
> path = os.getcwd()
> print("Current Directory", path)    
> # prints parent directory
> print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, os.pardir)))
> ```

**METHOD 3:**

> ```py
> import os.path 
>  
> # function to get parent 
> def getParent(path, levels = 1): 
>     common = path 
>   
>     # Using for loop for getting 
>     # starting point required for 
>     # os.path.relpath() 
>     for i in range(levels + 1): 
>   
>         # Starting point 
>         common = os.path.dirname(common) 
>   
>     # Parent directory upto specified 
>     # level 
>     return os.path.relpath(path, common) 
>   
> path = 'D:/Pycharm projects / GeeksforGeeks / Nikhil / gfg.txt'
> print(getParent(path, 2))
> ```

Keep in mind, that you can put these into functions and repeat them the number of parent directories up you need to go, for example you could turn method 1 into:

```py
import os

def get_parent_directory(num_of_parent_directories_to_go_up=1):  # Defaults the number of parent directories to go up to one, which mean go one directory up
    current_path = os.getcwd()
    for i in range(num_of_parent_directories_to_go_up):
        current_path = os.path.dirname(current_path)
    return current_path
```

This will output the parent directory of how many times you put into it, which defaults to one.

Example 1:

INPUT: `users/personal/project/scripts`

CODE: `get_parent_directory()`

OUTPUT: `users/personal/project/`

Example 2:

INPUT: `users/personal/project/scripts`

CODE: `get_parent_directory(2)`

OUTPUT: `users/personal/`

Ans you can see how this would go on. Furthermore, this does not error if you give a number larger than parent directories exist and will instead return the root path.

In the function or with what is returned from the example function I provided, you can use `os.chdir(path_from_function_here)` to change your working directory.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `os.getcwd()` to get the current path, then find out how many level to go back to project folder, then goto project folder using `os.chdir`

this will works across variable level deep inside project directory.

for example, current directory either in `/users/personal/project/scripts` or `/users/personal/project/scripts/lib` also will back to `/users/personal/project`

`os.path.sep` ensure this will works in both windows/linux

```
curdir = os.getcwd().split(os.path.sep)
project_back_idx = len(curdir) - curdir.index('project') - 1
os.chdir(os.path.sep.join(['..'] * project_back_idx))
# 1 level back - os.chdir('..')
# 2 level back - os.chdir('..//..') and so on
```